# Can we say $f(x)=\frac{x}{\ln(x^2)}$ has a removable discontinuity at $x=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, functions, continuity

I came across a function $$f(x)=\frac{x}{\ln(x^2)}$$

It is evident that $f(0)$ is undefined. But we have:
$$\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} f(x)=0=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{-}} f(x)$$

So is $x=0$ a removable discontinuity?

Comment: Yes. You could define $f(x)=x/\ln x^2$ for $x\neq0$ and $f(0)=0$ and then $f$ would be continuous at $0$, so the discontinuity of $f$ at $0$ is by definition removable.

Comment: That is what "removable discontinuity" means in a great many calculus texts.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $x = 0$ is a removable discontinuity. However, I think it is worth mentioning that if we work in the affinely extended real number system, then $\ln(0) = -∞$, and for any $a\in\mathbb R$, $a/\pm∞ = 0$, so the limit (both ways) would be equal to $0$.